# Auto boot and login to AWS Ubuntu server with Xfce

Tags: server, login, xfce, amazon-ec2, xrdp

I am somewhat new to linux and ubuntu, however, I am current running a ec2 instance with ubuntu server. I have setup xrdp to remote desktop into the server using the following guide: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-to-ubuntu-1604-windows/

That is all working great, the next step that I am trying to sort out is running xfce on startup and having it automatically login so I can run a startup script that will open a browser.

When I remote desktop into the instance, it appears to start xfce once I have logged in, runs the script that I have setup and works perfectly. Now, my issue is I want to automate this process so I don't have to login via RDP with xrdp.

I have tried creating a script that runs on startup that runs:

```
startx &
```

or

```
startxfce4 &
```

I have also added to the lightdm config:

```
autologin-username=<username>
```

I am lost as to what I need to do next, any help would be appreciated or any guidance as to where/what I should do next.

I don't need to use xfce, I only used it as that is what the AWS documentation recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer your question directly as I've never tried to setup rdp on linux, but I may have a better alternative.

I personally use [x2go](https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php) to get remote desktops on linux machines.  It uses ssh for encryption, and leaves the session running when you disconnect so you can pick up where you left off when you reconnect, and the best part, there are clients to allow you to connect to the x2go server for linux, Windows and Mac, so it's possible to use it just about anywhere.

Comment: Oh sweet, I will take a look at that. I am open to all ideas at the moment.